# Delete element of a table in a method

Tags: java, object, methods

What i wanna do is to remove an object from a table of object ONLY IF the object i wanna delete have the id i put in params.

Let's get into the code :

```
public static animals[] supprimerAnimals(int identifiant, animals[] liste){
    animals[] newOne = new animals[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < liste.length; i++){

    }
    return newOne;
}
```

This method will receive a id and a table in params.
In the table, we have objects... let's tell them animals. Here is a list of objects we could have :

```
liste[0] = animals(1, "cat", 6)
liste[1] = animals(2, "dog", 4)
```

here would be the constructor :

```
animals(int id, String type, int age);
```

So we have all we would need to get the solution.

So now let's get into an example...
If i do this :

```
animals[] zoo = supprimerAnimals(2, liste);
```

I need that zoo contains this :

```
zoo[0] = animals(1, "cat", 6);
```

Can you guys put me on the right way please ? 
I'm getting lock on the fact that i have to create a new table and i don't even now if the id will exist on the old table... So i can't fix the size of the new table...

Thank you guys

Comment: I guess this is a home work problem, So are you allowed to use Map?

Comment: Yes it's a home work and no i can't use map : /

Comment: Where is the table that you have created?

Comment: The whole program is more complicated than that... The table i use in my program comes from a text file... I simplified the program to you guys... But if we can resolve what i put in the post, i should be able to understand : ).

Answer (score 1):

```
animals[]
```

means that there is a java Object called animals, and the items in that array have this DataType "**animals**"

bellow i created an Object named Animal and here is an example with 2 ways of doing that

```
public class Animal{
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private int age;
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

    }
```

now some where you can implement the deleteMethods something like:

```
    public static Animal[] removeAnimal(Animal[] animals, int id) {
        List<Animal> list = Arrays.asList(animals);     
        for(Animal item : animals)
            if( item.getId() == id )
                list.remove(item);
        return list.toArray(animals);
    }
```

OR

```
    public static Animal[] removeAnimal2(Animal[] animals, int id) {
        Animal[] arr = new Animal[animals.length-1];
        int i = 0;
        for(Animal item : animals){
            if( item.getId() != id ){
                try{
                    arr[i]=item;
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this suits your need.

```
    public static animals[] supprimerAnimals(int identifiant, animals[] liste) {
        int supprimer = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < liste.length; i++) {
            if (liste[i].getId() == identifiant) {
                supprimer = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (supprimer < 0) {
            return liste;
        }
        animals[] nouveauListe = new animals[liste.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < supprimer; i++) {
            nouveauListe[i] = liste[i];
        }
        for (int i = supprimer + 1; i < liste.length; i++) {
            nouveauListe[i - 1] = liste[i];
        }
        return nouveauListe;
    }
```

**Note**
Java class names by convention are [PascalCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) and are singular, not plural

Answer (score 0):

Just Check out this. I have used list instead of Arrays.

```
package com.Hangman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List zoo= new ArrayList();
        Animal animal= new Animal(1,"cat",01);
        zoo.add(animal);
        animal= new Animal(6,"dog",02);
        zoo.add(animal);
        animal= new Animal(3,"mouse",03);
        zoo.add(animal);
        animal= new Animal(8,"rabbit",04);
        zoo.add(animal);
        animal= new Animal(5,"lion",05);
        zoo.add(animal);

        System.out.println("List of Animals in zoo");
        System.out.println(zoo);

        System.out.println("Animal to be removed from zoo is having id 3");
        removeFromZoo(zoo, 3);

        System.out.println("Animals in zoo after removal");
        System.out.println(zoo);

    }

    static void removeFromZoo(List zoo,int id){     
        Animal animal= new Animal(id,null, 0);      
            zoo.remove(animal);     
    }

}

class Animal{

    int id;
    String type; 
    int age;

    public Animal(int id, String type, int age) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {  
        return ""+this.type;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object animal) {      
        if(animal instanceof Animal){
        return this.id==((Animal) animal).id;   
        }else 
        return false;   

    }

}
```